# Spring Boot Admin does not notify when status changed to UP for an app running in Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, microsoft-teams, fabric8, spring-boot-admin

I have a spring-boot-admin running in Kubernetes. It uses the `spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8` to discover all services running in my cluster. This works fine and the journal show all status changes of a service.
[image: Journal]

I enabled spring-boot-admins ability to send notifications to MS Teams. But here I only get (De-)Registered notifications having the status `UNKNOWN`. It lacks the information about the status change to `UP`.
[image]

Is there anything missing to get proper status updates in MS Teams? Looks like it notifies MS Teams immediately once it is aware of a new pod but at this point the status is not `UP` yet.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason spring-boot-admins `AbstractStatusChangeNotifier` defines

```java
    /**
     * List of changes to ignore. Must be in Format OLD:NEW, for any status use * as
     * wildcard, e.g. *:UP or OFFLINE:*
     */
    private String[] ignoreChanges = { "UNKNOWN:UP" };
```

so there is no update for this change.

It can be changed with `spring.boot.admin.notify.ms-teams.ignore-changes:""`